# Django: Unknown column 'last_login' in 'field list'

Tags: python, django

I did look through other topics but I couldn't find anything useful or that would help me. All I did was doing `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` and then edit the file a bit, the user model and then did migrate.

Now when I try to create a super user I get this error

```
D:\Programming\Web\blaine county\website>python manage.py createsuperuser --username=andrei --email=andreigames9@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'last_login' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 161, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 144, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 73, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'last_login' in 'field list'")
```

This is my models.py https://pastebin.com/5sEY7t5H

The thing is that I had a legacy database and I tried to connect the app to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to consider when using user models and legacy databases.

In Django there are four `User` options built it and what you're trying to do here is not any of them.

First option is to use default `User` model, second option is to use `AbstractUser` model, third options is `AbstractBaseUser` and fourth option is linking back from a related model.

What you are trying to do here is to use `AbstractUser` option, but this doesn't work like that. `AbstractUser` options uses all of the field from base `User` models + additional fields defined in the model.

`AbstractBaseUser` is bare-bones option and uses three fields from default `User` model: `password`, `last_login`, `is_active` and whatever other fields you define in the model.

To make it work, you need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` and this will create `User` model with fields such as `last_login` plus all of your additional fields. **But you cannot do that, because you're using legacy database with `managed = False`.** It means:

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be
>   performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an
>   existing table or a database view that has been created by some other
>   means.

This means that with legacy database and `managed = False` option, you won't be able to make migrations and migrate, which consequently means that none of the Django options for `User` models are possible, because you'll always be missing one or another field.

If you're going to use legacy database and your own user model, then you need to dive deep into Django and rewrite (overwrite) at least authentication, login and logout functionalities, because they just won't work with your `Users` model. You can't just copy database that was created with EntityFramework (I assume) and expect it will work with Django.

You have more or less three sane options:

1. Ditch `Users` model from legacy database (you don't have to delete it, just change it from `AbstractBase` to `models.Model`) and setup your own in Django and then use legacy database just for storing data.
2. If you are allowed to do "whatever" with legacy database, switch tables you need to `managed = True`, delete fields that clash with Django `User` model in your `Users` model, make migrations and migrate.
3. Create new database and copy data from legacy database to new database.

Comment: and that's why I just wasted half an hour helping you

Comment: don't worry, I didn't mean that I am giving up, I did my own authenthication, but I was just saying

Comment: @Borut I changed `managed = False` to `managed = True` but I'm still getting the error after migration.  Do you have any clue why this might be?

Comment: No idea, it depends on what you did before that. Changing to custom user mid-project is difficult. Check [related documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) to get an idea. I did that once and it took me a few hours to get it working. Ever since I rather create new project, create custom user with initial migration, copy code from old project to a new one and migrate database. It's still quite a lot of work, but less painful. I suggest you start a new question describing your situation in detail.